# About deformation retract of pairs

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Here: [Relationship between homology of suspension of $X$ and $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322170/relationship-between-homology-of-suspension-of-x-and-x), Joe Moeller argued that $(\Sigma X\setminus U,C_-^n\setminus U)$ deformation retracts to $(C_+^n,X)$. I don't know the definition of deformation retracts of pairs, could someone tell me?

Comment: Do you know the concept of a deformation retract of spaces?