# Is there an analogue of the loop space for homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, loop-spaces

Is there an endofunctor $U: \mathrm{Top} \to \mathrm{Top}$ (or from some good subcategory) such that $H_n(UX) = H_{n+1}(X)$ for any $n \geq 1$

Comment: Yes: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322170/relationship-between-homology-of-suspension-of-x-and-x

Comment: @SergeyGuminov You should look more carefully at the indexing.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov That's a different question, yes, but I didn't regret reading that fact, thanks :)

Comment: @Aivazian Arshak. Yeah, I didn't notice the indexing. But as gor your question, I don't think such a thing exists, because by iterating $U$ you would get that all your homology vanishes, since $H^i$ vanishes for $i<0$.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov Why not an official answer?

Comment: @Paul Frost because I recently heard the term "desuspension" and was interested how it relates to this question.  But I guess it's a construction for something much more abstract than topological spaces.

Comment: Interesting question, even though the answer is that most likely no such functor  $U$ exists the proof of that would be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe such a functor exists, unless you restrict your attention to contractible spaces, which is uninteristing.

The reason is that then you would have $H_n(X)=H_{n-1}(UX)=\ldots=H_{-1}(U^{n+1}X)=0$.

Comment: I didn't think about the -1st homology group. Let n be natural in my question

Comment: More precisely, let $n > 0$ since $H_0$ of any space is a free abelian group.